# Fluid sim hitting an invisible wall in 3.2

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have googled for forever and found some things from 6 years ago but nothing that answers the issue and I'm pulling out my hair.

My fluid sim hits an invisible wall and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've boiled the project down to bare bones and there is no obstruction that I can see.  I have tried upping the resolution to 350 and changing Format Volumes from OpenVDB to Uni Cache. It will also crash on me after a time which is aggravating.  The drive I've pointed the cache to has 5TB of free space.

Here is the file if anyone wants to play with it. I'm going to go cry in a corner for a bit.

[Blender File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r1WDaflbZ_CN3OoSbInFO-agidGS6YhR/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I wasn't able to fully test the Blend file - I was getting a crash shortly after starting the simulation for some reason. I examined the Coil object and there seems to be some geometry issues that could potentially cause this type of problem. There are non-manifold edges located right where the liquid stops in your screenshot. There are also ~39k intersecting faces which could also cause problems. Tip: Blender's builtin 3D-Print toolbox addon can be enabled to analyze and highlight geometry issues.

Comment: It looks like you’re trying to shoot fluid out of the domain. Is this the case?

Comment: you have several issues here: 1) your outflow is super near to the domain side, so this will cause trouble with your simulation because of course all the domain sides are indeed "invisible" walls 2) you didn't apply scale & rotation to all of your fluid objects 3) your mesh geometry of the pipe is really strange - you should create it by creating a spiral curve, then use bevel value to get "clean" geometry which you can use in a simulation - of course bad geometry will stop or even crash such a simulation - after you repaired that and uploaded a new version, i will check again.

Comment: Thank you all for this information!  Sadly I did not make the coil; it was provided by a client.  I did apply a couple of solidify modifiers because the fluid was dribbling through at first, so perhaps this messed something up- I will reload the original version and see.  RLGUY thank you for the tips on how to correct the geometry issue! I will for sure try this out.

Not trying to shoot fluid out of the domain but through the pipe and coil.

Comment: Chris, thank you also.  I will adjust things based on your feedback, although I cannot create the curve myself as it has to look exactly like that and I'm less experienced with building than I am with animating.  I always forget to apply rotation and scale!  Grrr thank you, n00b move on my part.